# Flutter translate List of strings

Tags: flutter, dart, translation

I need help, i tried to translate a list of strings in flutter with [translator](https://pub.dev/packages/translator) package, but it keep displaying `_instance of 'Future<translation>'` this is my code:

```
            ListView.builder(
              itemCount: docs.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                translated((docs[index]['tweet']));
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text(
                    docs[index]['name'],
                    style:
                        TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                  subtitle: Text(
                      translator.translate(docs[index]['tweet']).toString()),
                );
              },
            );
```

i tried to use `async` and `await` with `setState()` in a sperated method like this:

```
String output = "";
  Future<void> translated(String post) async {
    final Translation translation = await translator.translate(post, to: 'en');
    final String out =  translation.toString();
    print(out);
    setState(() {
      output = out;
    });
  }
```

```
ListView.builder(
              itemCount: docs.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                translated((docs[index]['tweet']));
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text(
                    docs[index]['name'],
                    style:
                        TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                  subtitle: Text(output),
                );
              },
            );
```

It does translate but the value keep on changing infinitly while displaying .
**this is the full body:**

```
body: Container(
          child: StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('favorite')
            .doc(userID)
            .collection('Publication')
            .snapshots(),
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData)  {
            List<dynamic> docs = snapshot.data.docs;
            return FutureBuilder<List<String>>(
                      future: translated(),
                      builder: (context, snapshot) {
                        switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                          case ConnectionState.waiting:
                            return Text('Loading....');
                          default:
                            if (snapshot.hasError) {
                              return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
                            } else {
                              List<String> data = snapshot.data ?? [];

                              return ListView.builder(
                                itemCount: docs.length,
                                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                 
                                  return ListTile(
                                    title: Text(
                                      docs[index]['name'],
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 15.0,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                    ),
                                    subtitle: Text(data[index]),
                                  );
                                },
                              );
                            }
                        }
                      },
                    );
          } else {
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
        },
      )),
```

1. List item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `translated` inside `build method`, and call `setState` inside `translated`, means that you are calling `setState` inside `build method`, so you are rebuilding you widget again and again. Change you `translated` to this:

```
Future<String> translated(String post) async {
    final Translation translation = await translator.translate(post, to: 'en');
    final String out =  translation.toString();
    print(out);
    return out;
  }
```

and use it like this:

```
ListView.builder(
              itemCount: docs.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                String output = await translated((docs[index]['tweet']));
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text(
                    docs[index]['name'],
                    style:
                        TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                  subtitle: Text(output),
                );
              },
            );
```

**I recommended that you fallow this approach:**

```
FutureBuilder<List<String>>(
                      future: translated(),
                      builder: (context, snapshot) {
                        switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                          case ConnectionState.waiting:
                            return Text('Loading....');
                          default:
                            if (snapshot.hasError) {
                              return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
                            } else {
                              List<String> data = snapshot.data ?? [];

                              return ListView.builder(
                                itemCount: docs.length,
                                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                 
                                  return ListTile(
                                    title: Text(
                                      docs[index]['name'],
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 15.0,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                    ),
                                    subtitle: Text(data[index]),
                                  );
                                },
                              );
                            }
                        }
                      },
                    )
```

and change your `translated` to this:

```
Future<List<String>> translated() async{
    List<String> result = [];
    for (var element in docs) {
      String output = await translated((element['tweet']));
      result.add(output);
    }
    return result;
  }
```

Comment: @ahmed I updated my answer, check it out.

Comment: what is the type of docs ?

Comment: docs is your list you already  have in your code. @ahmed

Comment: are the translated() and you widgets and docs list in the same class? @ahmed

Comment: docs is inside the streambuilder, @eamirho3ein i just updated my question.

Comment: define List<dynamic> docs out of build method. And update it inside the streambuilder. @ahmed

Answer (score 0):

When you call a function in the **build** method of a widget, this function gets called infinitely, as long as the widget appears in the tree. No matter if the operation is asynchronous or not, you should call it in your initState() method - [official initState docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/NavigatorState/initState.html). If the action is async, you should make sure the widget that uses the data from the operation is called **AFTER** the operation is completed. This can be made in a variety of ways - for example: create a variable: `bool translationIsFinished = false;`, then, at the bottom of your translate function, call `setState(()=>translationIsFinished = true);`. And in your build method where your List Widget lies, use this:
`if(translationIsFinished)...[// your widget here]`
 Or alternatively, you can use the ternary operator like this:
`translationIsFinished ? YourWidget() : Container()`

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, it's better to translate the fetched posts before showing them so you can do it like this:

```
Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> translatePosts(List<Map<String, dynamic>> docs) async {
    for (var doc in docs) {
      final post = doc['tweet'];
      final Translation translation = await translator.translate(post, to: 'en');
      doc['tweet'] = translation.toString();
    }
    return docs;
  }
```

Then, to show that you can use the *FutureBuilder*:

```
FutureBuilder(
  future: translatePosts,
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: docs.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                translated((snapshot[index]['tweet']));
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text(
                    snapshot[index]['name'],
                    style:
                        TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                  subtitle: Text(output),
                );
              },
            );
    }

  }
)
```